# Phonegap - Failed to restore plugin "io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite"

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've inherited a Phonegap project that just contained the `www` folder. The `config.xml` contains this entry:

```
<plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite" source="pgb" />
```

When I run `cordova platform add android` or `cordova build`, I get this warning message:

*Discovered plugin "io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite" in config.xml. Adding it to the project. Failed to restore plugin "io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite*

I added the Sqlite plugin from https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage using the command `cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save`, then `cordova prepare`, and then proceeded to run the above, but still get the same warning message.

Is this something I can ignore, or is there something I can do to resolve it? Thank you!

---

**EDIT:** I am using Cordova CLI 6.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, that's the old PhoneGap Build version of the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin. PhoneGap Build has since moved to npmjs for hosting plugins, and [will be shutting down the old repository](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/10/13/pgb-repository-shutting-down/). You've probably already got the line:

```
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" source="npm" />
```

In your `config.xml` file. If so, just remove the line:

```
<plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite" source="pgb" />
```

And that should clear the error.

Comment: Hi eb1 and thanks for your reply! In the source files I was given, `<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" source="npm" />` was commented out, and below it was the entry `<plugin name="io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite" source="pgb" />`...there must've been a reason that the original developer had done this?

Comment: The API for creating a database did change post 0.8.2 (see https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database), which broke my builds for a bit until I had a chance to update things. It's possible the original developer ran into that -- or some other temporary build bug -- and decided to stay on the old plugin. But I've found the new plugin to be quite stable so far.

Comment: By the way, if you're not already doing this, you might want to add `spec="<plugin-version>"` attributes to your `<plugin>` lines in `config.xml`. Those tie your build to specific versions of the plugins, so your build doesn't break if a plugin's API changes (or fails to work). Link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#plugin

Comment: Thanks eb1. So I did what you suggested and the app built fine and loaded fine onto my phone, but did not seem to do anything thereafter where it should've first looked at sqlite storage to check for certain records, or pull them in from external source if they don't exist. I'm guessing there is a difference as u have said in the way the database is created initially. I'll have a look at how the previous developer did it against what the recommended method for `cordova-sqlite-storage`

Comment: Also check to make sure you're actually opening the database. The default location moved for the database (see that link in my first comment), which might be causing it to not find the database.

Comment: Apologies for my confusion, but which one are you referring to? `cordova-sqlite-storage` or `io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite`?

Comment: `cordova-sqlite-storage`, versions 0.8.2 and below. I'm guessing the old location applies to the `io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite` plugin as well, since the plugin is a bit dated (and the same guy wrote both plugins). See the Warning section under https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! Thank you. Everything began to work correctly when I changed from `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: database,location: 0});` to `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: database, location: 'default'});`. Thank you for your references